# Jumps in Python

Tags: python, exception

I would like to make a jump in Python code (like goto ...). 
I know Goto is poor programming, but I'm too 'deep' now to recreate my structure.

Besides, using functions wouldn't be a good idea because I don't want the program to continue running code that's after the function call.

I was thinking about raising an exception. I'm not sure if this would work.

Problem (simplified):

Let's say I'm freerunning.

If I press 'Left' My character should start running left, and when he hits a wall, he should start running right. 
(analogous for pressing 'Right')

In other words: when my character hits a wall I want the codeblock to STOP running and to start another codeblock.

Would exceptions work here?
Because I'm uncertain if the code under an exception raise would run even if the exception itself hasn't been encountered.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
My code: http://pastebin.com/QBy5x3g8 (dead)

Comment: Would be best if you show us your code!

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please just be specific and say why do you have to avoid functions and use goto. Showing some code would be a nice addition!

Comment: @aIKid that's a fantastic link, had never heard the phrase XY Problem before but it captures it perfectly.

Comment: "I'm too 'deep' know to recreate my structure." - I doubt it. It's pretty unlikely that much of your code is tangled to the point where a goto is the most straightforward solution, and still actually works. You know you *should* rewrite the mess you got yourself into, so do that instead of making up excuses why you won't throw out said mess.

Comment: After looking at your snippet, you should re-design your code.

Comment: OK, glancing at the code you linked to, it *seems* like you want to do things in 0.1second "turns". So, make that explicit. Run a single loop with 0.1 second pauses, and on every iteration of that loop, evaluate the current situation (collisions in the current direction, key last pressed, etc), and then decide what to do in the next step. Basically, you want to extract all the repetitions of `time.sleep()` somewhere, then flatten all the conditions you have - you're really only checking what the object in the current direction is, you don't need three levels of nested loops for that.

Comment: Also, chucking out 80 lines of code in order to make it have a sane design isn't really a lot.

Comment: I find it interesting that no one's pointed out that `goto` doesn't exist in python so even if it were a good idea for this project it couldn't be used.

Comment: The `isinstance(...)` everywhere is an "anti-pattern". Why aren't you using methods/attributes in all those places? Real finished code is never indented that deeply. Much of that logic would be better in methods of your objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I press 'Left' My character should start running left, and when he hits a wall, he should start running right. (analogous for pressing 'Right') In other words: when my character hits a wall I want the codeblock to STOP running and to start another codeblock.

That can be accomplished like this

```
# main loop
while True:

  # check for input and respond appropriately
  if left_key_pressed:
    # keep running left until you hit a wall
    while not hit_wall:
      run_left() 

    # hit a wall, do something after

  elif right_key_pressed:
    while not hit_wall:
      run_right()

    # hit a wall, do something after
```

There's no need to do any sort of explicit `Goto`

> Besides, using functions wouldn't be a good idea because I don't want the program to continue running code that's after the function call.

If you don't want the program to continue after a function call you can always explicitly terminate the program or throw an exception to crash it, but I doubt that's what you want to do. At least, as a user, I probably don't expect the program to just terminate on me because I hit a wall.

Answer (score 3):

"Jumps" are accomplished via function calls, if/else, while, and exceptions.  Depending or your code, any one of the above may be the right answer.  If none are, you need to redo your code, no matter how deep your are into it.

Answer (score 2):

> "I know Goto is poor programming, but I'm too 'deep' know to recreate
>   my structure."

You're never too deep to refactor your code. Asking for a `goto` is asking for lots of trouble that will dig you much deeper and make your problems much more intractable.

It looks like you're looking for a return statement inside a function handles and would interrupt your process.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Move your logic into methods. For example, if you have a "Sprite" class. Don't be afraid to have methods that do nothing if it's going to simplify your mainloop

```
class Player(Sprite):
    ...
    def handle_key(self, keystroke):
        if keystroke == "l":
            self.dx = -1
        elif keystroke == "r"
            self.dx = 1
    ...


    def move(self):
        self.x += self.dx
        self.y += self.sy
    ...    

class Wall(Sprite):
    ... 
    def handle_key(self, keystroke):
        pass
    ...
    def move(self):
        pass


...
def main():
    sprites = init_sprites()
    ...
    while True:
        for obj in sprites:
            obj.handle_key(keystroke)
            obj.move

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an exception:

```
try:
    move()
except Blocked:
    otherMove()
```

Or just use an if statement:

```
if canMove()
    move()
else:
    otherMove()
```

The problem with the first is it makes it easy to accidentally mutate the state before you throw exception. It is either easy to refactor it into the second option, or else it is likely to have some kind of unanticipated side effects. It is far easier to have a effects-free checking function followed by an function which always succeeds at changing the complete state.

Answer (score 0):

Use an exception:

```
class Goto(Exception):
    pass

try: 
    i=1    
    while True:
        while True:
            while True:
                while True:
                    i+=1
                    if i==100:
                        raise Goto
except Goto:
    print(i)
```